# Reduce / Lambda Iteration in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to iterate the formula using Reduce / Lambda such that you can just change the first sheet name and it will update accordingly.

Currently I am using a formula as so:

```
=DROP(UNIQUE(VSTACK(
FILTER('2023-12'!A:A,'2023-12'!A:A<>""),
FILTER('2023-11'!A:A,'2023-11'!A:A<>""),
FILTER('2023-10'!A:A,'2023-10'!A:A<>""),
FILTER('2023-09'!A:A,'2023-09'!A:A<>""),
FILTER('2023-08'!A:A,'2023-08'!A:A<>""),
FILTER('2023-07'!A:A,'2023-07'!A:A<>""),
FILTER('2023-06'!A:A,'2023-06'!A:A<>""),
FILTER('2023-05'!A:A,'2023-05'!A:A<>""),
FILTER('2023-04'!A:A,'2023-04'!A:A<>""),
FILTER('2023-03'!A:A,'2023-03'!A:A<>""),
FILTER('2023-02'!A:A,'2023-02'!A:A<>""),
FILTER('2023-01'!A:A,'2023-01'!A:A<>""))),5)
```

Similar to how you can SUM over multiple pages like =SUM('2023-12:2023-01'!A1), I would like to use a REDUCE LAMBDA so that I can update the first sheet from 2023-12 to 2024-01, etc and it will update the result accordingly.

The idea is that the sheets contain all items in column A, where new items are added almost monthly and the resultant column should make sure it has all results from all sheets in a unique list.

I hope this makes enough sense.

The formula above is what I have tried, and though it works, I have to add the new row in to the formula everytime I add the new period. This will eventually get really long and make the formula huge.

Comment: Are you able to instead append the new data to your existing table? May be work at first to paste all of them into one, but that combined with a column for the period would make for much more straightforward formula writing and maintenance.

Comment: Ideally, we would like to keep individual pages for data. Is there a good way then, to produce an aggregate page? =FILTER(VSTACK('2024-1:2023-1'!A:A),VSTACK('2024-1:2023-1'!A:A)<>"") will produce a #NUM! due to exceeding number of rows during the VSTACK portion of the formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know a way of doing it without using the volatile function Indirect, but if this is allowed it would look like this with Reduce:

```
=LET(startDate,DATE(2023,12,1),
seq,SEQUENCE(3,1,0,-1),
DROP(UNIQUE(REDUCE("",seq,LAMBDA(a,c,VSTACK(a,TOCOL(INDIRECT("'"&TEXT(EDATE(startDate,c),"YYYY-MM")&"'!"&"A:A"),1))))),1))
```

[image]

where the start date and number of sheets can be changed as required.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Utilizing SheetNames via Name Manager in Excel has enabled us to automate the process entirely, eliminating the need to manually adjust formulas. By employing Name Manager to define 'SheetNames' using the formula `=REPLACE(GET.WORKBOOK(1),1,FIND("]",GET.WORKBOOK(1)),"")`, we've generated an array containing all sheet names. By filtering this array to include only names with "-", we can seamlessly integrate it into your formula, simplifying the process. I appreciate your assistance in this, and thanks for pointing us in the right direction.